# Pygame window not Displaying

Tags: python, pygame

new to using the pygame module and have been trying to open a window but to no avail. Here's my code.

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

def main():

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried putting the SCREEN in the main function but that hasn't worked either. Pygame has been installed successfully (I get the Hello from the pygame community message). And I've tried reinstalling python but nothing seems to work. I've tried looking at other posts but they all have to do with the window closing immediately following launch, whereas mine absolutely nothing happens. I'm on a Windows computer but using WSL on VScode. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/#quick-start) and their quick-start.

It looks like you are missing `pygame.init()` in your code

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)  # limits FPS to 60

pygame.quit()
```

According to the [documentation `pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html#init) says:

> Before you can do much with pygame, you will need to initialize it. The most common way to do this is just make one call.
> `pygame.init()`
> This will attempt to initialize all the pygame modules for you. Not all pygame modules need to be initialized, but this will automatically initialize the ones that do.

Comment: It is not necessary to initialize all Pygame modules with .init(). The display module is initialized when you call .set_mode

Comment: You are right. Calling `pygame.display.set_mode()` implicitly initializes `display`. But the problem he is having is that no window opens. Re-reading the original post, he says he is running it under WSL. Could be a compability/configuration problem with his WSL setup and pygame.

Comment: If it is a problem with the system but not with the code, the question is off-topic. StackOverflow is about questions about the code, not the system.